# CherryPy Hello World error

Tags: localhost, port, cherrypy

When I am running CherryPy Hello World:

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld:
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world!"
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_port': 8080,})
cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

... I get this: IOError: Port 8080 not bound on 'localhost'. What could it be?

Comment: I've faced this problem before. I hope this question will help someone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've probably got something else listening on that port.

On Linux do:

```
netstat -pnl | grep 8080
```

And see what process is listening on 8080

On Windows use something like [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) to do the same.

Answer (score 9):

If you are trying to deploy CherryPy on Heroku, where you cannot use the loopback to check whether you have really opened a port, then you need to simply disable CherryPy's `wait_for_occupied_port()` function so that CherryPy's self-consistency check does not decide that it has, in fact, failed to start. Here are the three lines that I use to fix CherryPy so that it runs on Heroku:

```
    from cherrypy.process import servers
    def fake_wait_for_occupied_port(host, port): return
    servers.wait_for_occupied_port = fake_wait_for_occupied_port
```

Comment: While extremely useful this answer really doesn't belong here since it has very little to do with the OP's original question.  In this case it's more appropriate to __ask__ a more detailed and specific question to your very valuable answer, __then__ of course, answer it :).  I realize others have similar answers to this question here... but it's more of a thread hijack then anything.

Comment: My answer involves running that **exact** script and getting that **exact** error. I fail to see how that has "very little to do" with the question. You can see from @laurasia's answer that others think my answer relevant to this question as well.

Comment: Yeah, just confirmed I __do__ get the IOError and ChannelFailures: IOError, sometimes, and sometimes I just get SIGTERM.  So, you are right, I was wrong about the "very little to do" comment.  The lack of the error sometimes was the cause of my confusion.  I still would lean slightly towards a new thread though ;)

Comment: Great! Mokeypatch soultion ---> Also work if you doing MASQUERADE in iptables!

Answer (score 3):

As [Jason R. Coombs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767575/cherrypy-hello-world-error/3282264#3282264) wrote there is a problem with disabled loopback device. heroku.com has loopback disabled therefore CherryPy will crash. I [filed a bug](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/1100/cherrypy-322-gives-engine-error-when) for this.

Update: [Reported as resolved.](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/changeset/7e87ed84d9f4)

Answer (score 2):

I think I had a similar problem when I started using CherryPy...  But I can't remember exactly what it was...  But the fix involved using a config file instead of passing the configs by hand:

MyProj.conf:

```
[global]
server.socket_host = "127.0.0.1"
server.socket_port = 8080
server.thread_pool = 10
```

MyProj.py

```
import os
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld:
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world!"
    index.exposed = True

# Assumes the config file is in the directory as the source.    
conf_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
conf_path = os.path.join(conf_path, "MyProj.conf")
cherrypy.config.update(conf_path)
cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

This definitely works here.
I'm using Python 2.6.1 and CherryPy 3.1.1 and I run the script with `-W ignore`:

```
c:\My_path> python -W ignore MyProj.py
```

If you're under *nix, you should put the `-W ignore` in the `#!` comment at the top of the file.

Comment: The "-W ignore" is because CherryPy 3.1.1 isn't fully Python 2.6 ready; but it's still good enough for our internal needs here.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem yesterday on an Ubuntu Linux server. I spent a couple of hours trying to track down the bug in the CherryPy code before I realized that the error message is very generic. It will give this error message even if the host doesn't own the IP address to which the server is attempting to bind. In my case, the loopback interface (lo, 127.0.0.1) was disabled. Thus, even if I set `server.socket_host='0.0.0.0'`, the attempt to check the port, `wait_for_occupied_port`, would fail (as it assumes, reasonably, that the loopback interface is always available). After re-enabling the loopback interface, the CherryPy server would start up normally.

Update: CherryPy 3.2.3 has a fix for this particular issue. Until 3.2.3 is released, development builds are available on the [CherryPy project downloads](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/downloads).

Answer (score 1):

- Use it on different port (8000 for example)
- Read about [ConfigApi](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/ConfigAPI) (once again)
- Try latest version not 3.0
- Also this can be caused by some Windows firewall (Eset smart security or maybe other). So just use it on different port.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on OS X, try calling:

```
sudo lsof -i :8080
```

which will tell you the process using that port.

Answer (score 0):

AVG Anti-Virus was causing this problem for me.  Uninstalling AVG (far from ideal) did the trick.  I suspect the link scanner that I couldn't disable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when running CherryPy 3.2.2 on my Win7 PC with Python 3.3
The server would start normally and then would crash in about a couple of minutes.

I've applied the [patch](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/changeset/7e87ed84d9f4) from CherryPy 3.2.3 laurasia mentioned. But it didn't help.

So I had to comment out the lines raising the error at the very end of `python\Lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\servers.py` to prevent the server from dying:

```
...
#    if host == client_host(host):
#        raise IOError("Port %r not bound on %r" % (port, host))
...
```

Comment: I had the same problem, with the same setup, only on OS X. I just commented out the very last line in the same file. `raise IOError("Port %r not bound on %r" % (port, host))`

Answer (score 0):

### Windows 10

If you get a python exception printed to stdio that 8080 is not free on 127.0.0.1, then what you do is this:

```
netstat -o -a
```

at the windows command prompt.  Doing `netstat -o` alone will give you an incorrect PID.

Look for 8080 in the address string in the first column.  Once found, go horizontally over to the last column which is the PID (process ID).

Now to kill a process, I use `kill <PID>` which is part of an mysys install. I found that out by doing `where kill` on my system.

Thus all together:

```
netstat -o -a
[find PID then hit ctrl-c to stop netstat]
kill 13164
```

where 13164 is an example PID found in the first step.

If you do not have mysys installed, then install it or else look up how to kill a process by its PID on windows.