# CherryPy fails to bind to port

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-2.6, cherrypy

Thanks for your expertise, everyone. We're running a python server using Cherrypy to expose/handle our API. This use to run fine before upgrading Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04 (with inherent python updates), but, unfortunately, since then CherryPy does not bind to port 80 (using a proxy port 9998). The error dump is as follows:

```
2015-03-24 23:21:16,610 cherrypy.error - INFO - [24/Mar/2015:23:21:16] ENGINE PID 17194 written to '/var/tmp/MYSERVERNAME.pid'.
2015-03-24 23:21:16,611 cherrypy.error - INFO - [24/Mar/2015:23:21:16] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
2015-03-24 23:21:16,611 cherrypy.error - INFO - [24/Mar/2015:23:21:16] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
2015-03-24 23:21:21,771 cherrypy.error - ERROR - [24/Mar/2015:23:21:21] ENGINE Error in 'start' listener <bound method Server.start of <cherrypy._cpserver.Server object at 0x12ffa90>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 147, in publish
    output.append(listener(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cherrypy/_cpserver.py", line 90, in start
    ServerAdapter.start(self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 60, in start
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 101, in wait
    wait_for_occupied_port(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 266, in wait_for_occupied_port
    raise IOError("Port %r not bound on %r" % (port, host))
IOError: Port 9998 not bound on '127.0.0.1'
```

Running netstat to see what is occupying the port shows:

```
alpha$ sudo netstat -pnl | grep 8080
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17194/python
```

As you can see, the python server with PID 17194 starts up, starts cherrypy (which fails). I'm not sure what's colliding with what here. As you can probably tell, I'm not a server guy but that doesn't stop me from mucking around and messing things up! Anyone have a clue why CherryPy might not be binding?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CherryPy Hello World error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767575/cherrypy-hello-world-error)

Answer (score 2):

I uninstalled CherryPy and reinstalled CherryPy to the latest (3.2), and the problem resolved itself.

Comment: If you think this answer will help future readers who come across it, you should upvote your answer and mark it as correct.